# Is it possible to have a relationship between two supertypes?

Tags: entity-relationship

Say I have two supertypes, where every subtype of each supertype would have a relation. Could I have a relationship between the two supertypes? Or a relation between a supertype and an entity type?

Comment: Can you provide a small concrete example?

Comment: For example, if I had a user supertype with different types of users. All of these users would be able to leave reviews on developers, publishers or video games (company being a supertype of developers and publishers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.  In your example, you could easily include user_id and company_id in your review table.  Being able to do this kind of thing is the point of having a supertype in the first place.